# How to secure Cross-Domain request; allowing third website to POST data

Tags: php, ajax, security, csrf

I have done some researches on how to prevent fake cross-origin requests and have found a lot of useful information. However, none of them seems to directly resolve my concerns, and because my application has to deal with this specific situation, I would like to understand it completely.

I have a simple php mailing website: mailsite.com

This site will allow other pre-defined addresses, for instance, user.com, to send POST data to it, and process the information that contains `to` and `mesaage`; then send them an E-mail from mailsite.com to `to` with the message `message`.

Currently, I am using `$_SERVER[ "HTTP_ORIGIN" ]` and `$_SERVER[ "HTTP_REFERER" ]` to check where the requests come from; and process them if it is from the pre-defined domains. However, I've read some articles that say:

1. HTTP_ORIGIN is not even indexed in PHP documentation, because it is pretty much per-browser sort of thing, so browsers that refuse to send those information will not work. HTTP_REFERER is easy to fake.
2. Tokens are good in preventing CSRF.

However, the request I allow is coming from a third pre-defined website, how does Tokens work in this situation?

My question is: If I allow specific domains to POST data to my site, how can I make sure (or the most secured way) that those requests are coming from the sites I expected? Is HTTP_ORIGIN not even safe enough to use? I dare to think about allowing third website to POST data to my site because I've seen Facebook allowing people to access their database. There must be some possible solutions for checking where the requests come from.

Comment: I'm sure you meant `$_SERVER[ "HTTP_REFFERAL" ]` right? You made a typo.

Comment: Yes. I am so sorry for the typo. I typed it from my phone. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: Do you need to support browsers that don't support CORS? Otherwise not exactly clear what your concerns are...

Comment: @Fred-ii I'm sure you meant [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) right? ;)

Comment: Yes @GeorgeCummins I too stand corrected. I took it from OP's [`original post`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23576001/1). Had forgotten the underscore.

Comment: Hi Alexei. I meant that from my PHP server, how do I know exactly which site is sending request to my site? I currently use HTTP_ORIGIN but it was said to not be supported by all browsers; and HTTP_REFERER is fake-able. If there is no way, I am looking for an alternative solution such as sending custom header or something. I am quite new about cross-domain.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have multiple solutions possible:

- Use a token permission system. Give user.com a private token to add as a hidden value to the input form. Upon submitting this form, the browser will give your server the token, and the user shouldn't have to know about the token. You check the token against your own database. If you find the token, allow the mail to be sent.
- Use **CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)**. When an Ajax request is sent to your server from user.com, there should be multiple `Access-Control` headers. You check if these exist and what their values are using `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_header']` where `header` is one of the `Access-Control` header names. If these values match up to your expectations, respond with multiple `header('Access-Control-header: value');` calls so that the browser knows you accepted the preflight request, otherwise don't add any extra headers. The browser will send another request after the preflight, and this is when you'll actually send the mail.
- If this is being sent from user.com's server rather than a visitor of user.com, most likely the server's IP address won't change (though it may or may not use a defined range of IPs, so be mindful of that.), so you could verify that the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` matches a value in your database. You can keep a table of approved IP addresses in your database for this purpose. If you find the IP address in your table, allow the mail to be sent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: About the third point, I think it won't be a good practice to do so, as what if user.com is on a shared hosting?

Comment: Then it gets a bit more tricky. You could keep a table of approved domain names, and then IP addresses for that domain name. Use a script that executes on a cronjob to periodically do lookups on each domain name and map its IPs into your database, removing older entries for that domain that no longer come up in the lookup, and adding any new IPs that the lookup found. When the request comes in, verify against any of those IPs. You can also add in checking the reverse-DNS of that IP, and see if its DNS is in your approved domain names.

Comment: shared hosting = multiple domain single ip.

Comment: Hi Jailout2000. Thank you so much for the answer. Can I have 2 quick questions? 1) User A visits site.com; is the REMOTE_ADDR returns user A's IP or site.com's IP? 2) Only the CORS seems possible for me now, do you have a very quick and basic example of it from the server side? I've looked it up, but it seems to be just a little more than HTTP_ORIGIN, while HTTP_ORIGIN is not really reliable. The HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_header is something that can be coded using Javascript, which mean it is vulnerable, doesn't it?

Comment: @user3622260 answer to your first question is: it will return `site.com`'s IP.